# ldap_modify Error Object class violation

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to modify the notes/info section in AD and i'm getting Object class violation. Can anyone help please.(also tried ldap_mod_add / ldap_mod_replace)

```
$userName ='username';
set_time_limit(30);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);


$ldapserver = 'server';
$ldapuser      = 'user';  
$ldappass     = 'passowrd';
$ldaptree    = "ou=Sites,dc=folder,dc=local";
$justthese = array("samaccountname", "employeeId", "mobile","info");
// connect 
$ldapconn = ldap_connect($ldapserver) or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");

if($ldapconn) {

    $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldapuser, $ldappass) or die ("Error trying to bind: ".ldap_error($ldapconn));

    if ($ldapbind) {
        $result = ldap_search($ldapconn,$ldaptree, "(samaccountname=$userName)", $justthese) or die ("Error in search query: ".ldap_error($ldapconn));
        $data = ldap_get_entries($ldapconn, $result);
        //echo $ldapUserName = $data[0]["info"][0];

        $userdata["info"][0] = "test test";

        ldap_modify ($ldapconn, $ldaptree, $userdata);
        echo ldap_error($ldapconn);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with my DN.

Changed from this.

```
ou=Sites,dc=folder,dc=local
```

to this,

```
CN=name, OU=USERS, ou=Denver, ou=Sites, dc=folder, dc=local
```